# Mahapps Hamburger Menu - doesnt change menu item width

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I want to use the mahapps `HamburgerMenu` - but the `HamburgerMenuItems` get cutted when the Hamburger-Menu is "collapsed".

[Here](http://lh4.ggpht.com/-UgAGBBcqi6I/VS7jhHAJx_I/AAAAAAAAQTY/N1TzXUut-dE/SplitView_thumb.gif?imgmax=800) you can see it working, but if i change the Width in my `ItemTemplate` to a bigger value - the HamburgerMenu crops it instead of showing it completly.

All the examples work with 48 `Width` like [here](http://jkarger.de/2017/02/06/mahapps-hamburgermenu/).

So my question is:

**How to change the width of collapsed Hamburger MenuItems? So I Can use a Picture in it with 100 width!**

I thougth it is a hard coded value in the `ControlTemplate` of the HamburgerMenu, but didnt found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `CompactPaneLength` property of the `HamburgerMenu` to `100`:

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu CompactPaneLength="100" ...>
```

You may also want to set the `HamburgerWidth` property.

Comment: there is no `HamburgerMenu` in `"http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"` how can I access it? Is it available in simple WPF windows app?